# Cloud computing for c# developer

Tags: c#, azure, cloud

I am a c# developer but I really want to learn cloud computing.I googled many article and got the idea that Azure is best option to go into cloud computing for C# developer.However, Azure do not have SAAS so my question is "Is it worth going into paas/iaas with c# as my background?".
I fear that If I go into Azure ,I could not get any chance to use software development knowledge.

Please guide and if possible any tutorial link.

Thanks

Comment: I understand negative 1 but please provide answers too as already gave -1.Its a humble request .Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Azure do not have SAAS so my question is "Is it worth going into paas/iaas with c# as my background?".

Firstly, Azure’s compute offerings fall into three main categories: IaaS, PaaS and SaaS. [This article](http://robertgreiner.com/2014/03/windows-azure-iaas-paas-saas-overview/) explained and compared them with each other, please check it.

Secondly, as a developer, Azure could help you to develop and scale new applications or run existing applications in the public cloud. And you could use the services (such as storage, networking etc) that Azure provides to achieve your application requirements.

Besides, [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/fundamentals-introduction-to-azure) could help you know the fundamentals of Azure.

Comment: Thanks Sir .I started with tutorilaspoint.com and they said "The services provided by Microsoft Azure are PaaS and IaaS."Beside  as per my understanding,Cloud computing has 3 parts -SAAS/PAAS/IAAS and  PAAS & IAAS (supported by Azure)will not have any development related work.Its just configuration and deployment space

Comment: Some configuration and deployment related work could be achieved via REST API or client SDK, which could be also programming related work.

Comment: Sorry to bother ,So PAAS/IAAS are baasically do not require any sodtware development skill? Azure so not have SAAS as per the tutorial (tutorilaspoint.com)I am following